# JOOQ code generation - combining multiple schemas to single package

Tags: maven, code-generation, jooq

I have multiple schemas that contain tables which are going to be moving between different schemas. This of course causes that the imports are going to be broken from time to time as the tables move between different schemas.

Is there any way to combine these multiple schemas so that all the imports come from same package so I would not have to change the imports if the table moves from schema A to schema B. So I would have imports such as:

```
import company.jooq.tables.TABLEA
import company.jooq.tables.TABLEB
```

instead of having imports such as:

```
import company.jooq.schemas.SchemaNameA.tables.TABLEA
import company.jooq.schemas.SchemaNameB.tables.TABLEB
```

I have tried to create an own GeneratorStrategy. It creates the packages correctly but it fails in the compilation phase because the Keys file gets overriden by different schemas and thus it does not contain all the needed Keys. Then I tried to utilize the relations tag in my pom.xml to get rid of the generation of the Keys.java file but it still generates the Keys.

```
<generate>
    <relations>false</relations>
</generate>
```

What I'm doing seems to be a bit against how the things should be done but is there any way to get this kind of setup working with JOOQ? It doesn't really matter even if it is a bit hacky as this situation is only temporary.

The interesting parts of pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <jooq.version>3.10.2</jooq.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.39</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <url>${db.url}</url>
                    <user>${db.user}</user>
                    <password>${db.password}</password>
                </jdbc>
                <generator>
                    <strategy>
                       <name>my.generator.GeneratorStrategy</name>
                    </strategy>
                    <database>
                        <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
                        <includes>.*</includes>
                        <excludes>del_.*|tmp_.*|</excludes>
                        <schemata>
                            <schema>
                                <inputSchema>${db.schemaA}</inputSchema>
                                <outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>
                            </schema>
                            <schema>
                                <inputSchema>${db.schemaB}</inputSchema>
                                <outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>
                            </schema>
                        </schemata>
                    </database>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>jooq.schemas</packageName>
                        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                    </target>
                    <generate>
                        <javaTimeTypes>true</javaTimeTypes>
                        <relations>false</relations>
                    </generate>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
        <version>${jooq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>${jooq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: What jOOQ version are you using? Because turning off the generation of relations should turn off the generation of `Keys.java`

Comment: I was using jOOQ version 3.9.1 updating to 3.10.2 did not solve this problem. The Keys.java file is still generated. I even tried removing all other but one schema but the problem still occurs. I will edit the whole pom.xml to the question if it helps spotting the problem.

Comment: Interesting, I cannot reproduce this. Have you tried stepping through the generation with a debugger to see why the file is generated?